# Iphone developer account :- dont have distribution option

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

One friend's iphone developer account have only developer tab in iphone portal program, no distribution tab exists.

can he still submit app to app store? if yes how?

What to be done for distribution option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Only the Agent can submit apps.

Comment: Why, it has no option for distribution?

Comment: me and my friend both are new to development.
who are team agents?
how can individual account holder submit their apps?